How can I verify whether the email exists using Firebase?
I have implemented the firebase authentication using google and using email and password but the issue is the user can just type in the email that just does not exist. So how can i make sure that the email exists using firebase in android. In kotlin
I tried looking about this online but couldn't understand what is going on.

First, use sendEmailVerification.  The below example is from Manage Users in Firebase: Send a user a verification email in the Firebase documentation:
val user = Firebase.auth.currentUser

user!!.sendEmailVerification()
    .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Email sent.")
        }
    }

To check whether the user is verified, use isEmailVerified (example from Manage Users in Firebase: Get a user's profile):
// Check if user's email is verified
    val emailVerified = it.isEmailVerified


That works.   Alternatively, use an email link to sign in as that combines signing in with email verification into one step.
